# In SAS: How to flag unique combinations of a set of variable values

Tags: sas

In SAS, how can I create an identifier for each unique combination of a set of variables?

I have, for example, a several thousand observations with a dichotomous value for six variables. There are 2^6 unique combinations for the values of these variables for each observation. I would like to create an identifier for each unique combination, and eventually group my observations according to this value.

Have:

```
SubjectID     Var1     Var2     Var3     Var4     Var5     Var6
---------------------------------------------------------------
ID1           1        1        1        1        1        1        
ID2           1        0        1        1        1        1  
ID3           0        1        1        1        1        1  
ID4           0        0        1        1        1        0  
...           ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
ID3000        1        1        0        1        0        0
```

Want:

```
SubjectID     Var1     Var2     Var3     Var4     Var5     Var6     Identifier
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID1           1        1        1        1        1        1        A        
ID2           1        1        1        1        1        1        A
ID3           0        1        1        1        1        1        B  
ID4           0        0        1        1        1        0        C  
...           ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
ID3000        1        1        0        1        0        0        Z
```

`A` would represent 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 as a unique combination and `B` would represent 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 etc.

I have thought about creating a dummy variable based on 64 Var1-Var6 conditional statements. I've also thought about concatenating the values from Var1-Var6 into a new row to create a unique identifier.

Is there a more straightforward way of going about this?

I prefer an approach that assigns a specific identifier to a specific combination of the values, rather than one that just generates some arbitrary unique string whenever a new combination comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proc summary works well with the LEVELS option.  This technique works for any values of the group variables numeric or character.

```
data have;
   input (v1-v6)(1.);
   cards;
111111
111110
111101
111011
110111
;;;;
proc print;
proc summary data=have nway;
   class v1-v6;
   output out=unique(drop=_type_) / levels;
   run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not just concatenate the values?
So your combinations are:

```
111111
111110
111101
111011
110111
....
```

You can use PROC FREQ to check the number of each type.

```
proc freq data=have;
table var1*var2*var3*var4*var5*var6 / out=want list;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the unique values of the given variables' combinations and then creating an alphabetical List of Ids, you can create the result

```
data inp;
length combined $6.;
input subjectid $4. v1 1. v2 1. v3 1. v4 1. v5 1. v6 1.;
combined=compress(v1||v2||v3||v4||v5||v6);
datalines;
ID1 111111
ID2 011111
ID3 001111
ID4 111110
ID5 000111
ID6 111111
ID7 000111
;
run;

proc sql;
create table uniq
as
select distinct combined from inp order by combined desc;
quit;

data uniq1;
 set uniq;
 retain alphabet 65;
 Id=byte(alphabet) ;
 alphabet+1;

 drop alphabet;
run;

proc sql;
create table final_ds
as
select subjectid, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, Id
from inp a
left join uniq1 b
on a.combined=b.combined;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is sorted by your grouping variables then just use BY group processing.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by var1-var6 ;
  groupid + first.var6 ;
run;
```

Or you could just convert the 6 binary variables into a single unique value.

```
group2 = input(cats(of var1-var6),binary6.);
```

This has the added value of not requiring that you sort the data, but it does need for none of the grouping variables to be missing.

Result

```
SubjectID  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Identifier Want groupno group2
ID4  0  0  1  1  1  0 C  1  14
ID3  0  1  1  1  1  1 B  2  31
ID1  1  1  1  1  1  1 A  3  63
ID2  1  1  1  1  1  1 A  3  63
```